# Invoke step function from AWS Aurora postgreSQL Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, cloud, aws-step-functions

The project I'm working on requires creating an DB aurora (PostgreSQL) that will invoke my step function (After every insert to X table) and gets the result from the step function to invoke a lambda function.

So the question : How can I invoke (and sent data) step function in every insert to my X table? (I am open to any solutions)

Answer (score 2):

RDS has a [Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html) that you can use to send CRUD events from your PostreSQL database to Lambda.  Your Lambda would then [start execution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_StartExecution.html) of your Step Function with an SDK call.

Follow the steps in the AWS blog post [Enable near real-time notifications from Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL by using database triggers, AWS Lambda, and Amazon SNS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/enable-near-real-time-notifications-from-amazon-aurora-postgresql-by-using-database-triggers-aws-lambda-and-amazon-sns/), but invoke Step Functions from your Lambda instead of SNS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to Invoke a step function directly from Aurora DB, the step function [can be invoked by](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-invoke-sfn.html):

1. AWS Lambda, using the StartExecution call.
2. Amazon API Gateway
3. Amazon EventBridge
4. AWS CodePipeline
5. AWS IoT Rules Engine
6. AWS Step Functions

There is a way to Invoke a lambda from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster([Invoking an AWS Lambda function from an Aurora PostgreSQL DB cluster](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/PostgreSQL-Lambda.html)), but it is not easy, you can follow the steps in the article, and in the **Lambda step**, you can Invoke your step function, your solution can be:

```
Aurora > Lambda > Step Function > Lambda
```

And not:

```
Aurora > Step Function > Lambda
```

Even if you are using a DynamoDB stream, you need to Invoke a Lambda first, you can't Invoke a step function directly.